# CSS3 animation begin when hovering over a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a navigation bar that I'm trying to get two links to animate in from off-page and end  next to my other links when I hover over one of the links in my list.

Current navigation links:

```
<div class="links">
  <ul>
     <li>
         <a href="#">link 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="#">link 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="#">link 3</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the css for .links:

```
.links ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    left: 60%;
    z-index: 4; 
    width: auto;
    height: 67px;
}

.links li  {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 40px;
}
```

And here's the relevant css, along with the animation that I have currently that works properly:

```
.extralinks {
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    left: 90%;
    animation-name: slidey;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-play-state: running;
/* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-name: slidey;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    z-index: 4;
}

@keyframes slidey {
    0% {left: 90%; top: 8px;}
    100% {left: 40%; top: 8px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidey /* Safari and Chrome */ {
    0% {left: 90%; top: 8px;}
    100% {left: 40%; top: 8px;}
}

.links li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: Red;
}
```

markup for .extralinks

```
<div class="extralinks">
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#">link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">link 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to make it so that when someone hovers over "link 3" the animated links slide in from the right and end next to my links. I'm not quite sure how exactly to link the animation to "link 3" in my list. Any help? I would not be opposed to using javascript/jquery, I'm just not well-versed in either.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the markup for `.extralinks` look like? (And where is it relative to the `.links` container)?

Comment: editted my post with the extra info! thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear of your goals, but I made some assumptions and slapped a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/fMtz6/) together. I used css transitions instead because I assumed it was a :hover animation and this allowed the sub menu to return to it's position.

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.links {
    width:100%;
}
.links > menu {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.links menu li  {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding:0.75em 1em;
}
.l3 .extralinks {
    position:absolute;
    top:2em;
    left:100%;
    z-index: 4;

    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.l3:hover .extralinks {
    left:0;    
}
.l3:hover .extralinks li {
    display:block;
}
.links li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: Red;
}

    <div class="links">
      <menu>
         <li>
             <a href="#">link 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#">link 2</a>
         </li>
         <li class="l3">
             <a href="#">link 3</a>
             <menu class="extralinks">
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">link 4</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="#">link 5</a>
                 </li>
             </menu>
         </li>
      </menu>
    </div>
```